# Is Wikipedia correct about bounded sets?

Tags: general-topology

In its [article on bounded sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set), Wikipedia states:
“The word bounded makes no sense in a general topological space without a metric.”
However, I was always under the impression that a bounded set in a general topological space was defined to be any subset of a compact subset of the space. Is this not correct? I did some googling, but was unable to pinpoint any such definition, but still that was my impression.

Comment: I think it just may be your impression.

Comment: I have also seen someone using that definition. As a definition it is perfectly ok for anyone to stated and use it. On the other hand, it is not a very fitting definition. For example, if you take an infinite set with the discrete metric. Every subset is bounded, but the infinite ones are not compact.

Comment: You may be interested in thinking about *total boundedness*. The characterization of "compact" as equivalent to "complete and totally bounded" seems very relevant here. Note subsets of totally bounded sets are totally bounded, so even better. I won't try to explain -- Google is your friend.

Answer (score 4):

Boundedness is stated in terms of a metric. It is a *metric* property, not a *topological* property. The real line is homeomorphic to the interval $(0,1)$, yet with the Euclidean metric on each, one is bounded and the other is not.

In fact, given a metric space $(X,d)$, one can form the corresponding bounded metric $\hat{d}\equiv \min\{d,1\}$. Then the metric spaces $(X,d)$ and $(X,\hat{d})$ have exactly the same open sets (i.e., the metrics are equivalent), so they are topologically indistinguishable, but the second space is bounded (one always has $\hat{d}(x,y)\leq 1$) while the first needn't be.

Answer (score 1):

It seems intuitively close to what "bounded" should mean, and I don't know that we can come any closer using just the topology. That being said, it doesn't correspond to the notion of "bounded" for metric spaces, and as such doesn't deserve the name "bounded" in my opinion. To see what I mean, look at other examples of terms that have both an analytical and topological definition, like "continuous", "converge" and "compact": the analytical and topological notions agree on metric spaces.

As an illustrating counterexample, take the real numbers with the discrete metric. It is bounded the classical way, but nowhere near contained in a compact subset of the space.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not a topologist, I must say that I have never met the definition of boundedness in general topology. Anyway, it is meaningful in topological *vector* spaces, since there is a natural definition of dilation. In that framework, a set $E$ is bounded if for every open neighborhood $U$ of zero, there exists $t>0$ such that $E \subset tU$.

Since open balls are never compact in infinite dimensionnal Banach spaces, your definition is troublesome.